# How to limit the character amount you are selecting from

Tags: sql, sql-server, average

I'm trying to average a field and it's very simple to do but there are some problems with some values. There are values I know are way too big and I was hoping to exclude them by the number of characters (I would probably put 4 characters max).

I'm unfamiliar with a sql clause that could execute this. If there is one that would be great.

```
select avg(convert(float,duration)) as averageduration
from AsteriskCalls where ISNUMERIC(duration) = 1
```

I expect the output to be around 500-1000 but it comes up as an 8 digit number.

Comment: Is `duration` numeric (even if not a `float`)?  You could use `WHERE duration < 10000`

Comment: Careful with `ISNUMERIC`, it gives wrong results (`ISNUMERIC('.')` returns 1, and `ISNUMERIC('')` returns 0, but the opposite is true for trying to convert the values). You should really use `TRY_CONVERT` or `TRY_CAST`.

Answer (score 1):

That is easy enough:

```
select avg(convert(float,duration)) as averageduration
from AsteriskCalls
where ISNUMERIC(duration) = 1 and length(duration) <= 4;
```

This will not necessarily work, of course, because you could have `'1E30'`, which would be a pretty big number.  And it would miss `'0.001'`, which is a pretty small number.

The more accurate method uses `try_convert()`:

```
select avg(try_convert(float, duration)) as averageduration
from AsteriskCalls
where try_convert(float, duration) <= 1000.0
```

And that should probably really be:

```
where abs(try_convert(float, duration)) <= 1000.0
```